# How can I show/hide programs using in tray wmctrl?

Tags: linux, notification-area, wmctrl

I'm trying to make my onboard hide/show with a keyboard shortcut (I know ironic, please don't ask why). However I couldn't find a way to do it in their manual, it only shows programs that are windowed programs that can go to tray. However onboard is completely tray program it doesn't have a window name, is it possible to work around that with wmctrl?

I tried to find it with `$ wmctrl -l` but it didn't show up then I tried `$ wmctrl -r "onboard" -b toggle,shaded` which not surprisingly didn't work either.

I'm using Linux Mint with Cinnamon.